# Finding the generators of the adjoint representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

Let $G$ be a lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ it's associated lie algebra.I can quite easily show that if there is a Lie group representation $\rho_{G}$ from $G$ into $L(G)$: 
$$ \rho_{G}: G \rightarrow \mathfrak{g} \;  ; g \rightarrow Ad(g)  $$ 
Such that for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$,  $Ad(g)X:=gXg^{-1}$ 
Then we have a **corresponding lie algebra representation** $\rho_{\mathfrak{g}}$: 
$$ \rho_{\mathfrak{g}}: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow End(\mathfrak{g}) \; ; X \rightarrow ad(X)$$ 
Such that $ ad(X)Y = [X,Y]$

- But why is it true that the generators of this are the structure constants? (i.e the basis of the adjoint algebra is the structure constants?)

Since $ad$ is just a LA homomorphism, if $T_{\alpha}$ is a generator of $\mathfrak{g}$ then, $ad(T_{\alpha})$ must be a generator of $End(\mathfrak{g})$? But $ad(T_{\alpha}) = [T_{\alpha},-]$ Clearly I'm seriously confused about something here...

**EDIT**

- I think my confusion has something to do with a lack of understanding of dual spaces.(?)

  - The point is, $ad(T_{\alpha}) = [T_{\alpha},-]$ is indeed the corresponding basis *operator* in the adjoint representation
  - However that operator can be defined (in a certain basis) as a matrix - and the natural basis to define that matrix in is our original $\{T_{\rho}\}$. In which case:

$$ ad(T_{\alpha})_{\text{Basis of}\mathfrak{g}} = \begin{pmatrix} [T_{\alpha},T_{1}].... [T_{\alpha},T_{n}] \end{pmatrix} $$

- So that the **components** of $ad(T_{\alpha})$ in this basis are indeed the structure constants - although technically, it is more correct to say that $ad(T_{\alpha})$ is the abstract generator?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377429/2451