# Calculating adjoint representation of Lie group/algebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

How do I calculate [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) of Lie group and Lie algebra? I would be thankful if anyone can give good example or general formula on calculating adjoint of any Lie group

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377429/2451

Comment: This question is very dense. On what level are you asking?

Comment: I took the introductory book Group theory for Physicist by JF Cornwell. He calculates adjoint of representation using formula.