Lie algebra adjoint representation
I'm currently reading Maggiore's book on QFT. He's explains Lie groups and Lie algebra right now. There is a point he makes which I cannot really follow. Its about how the adjoint represantation satisfies the Lie algebra.
His point:
A representation of special importance is the adjoint representation. Which has the same dimension as number of generators.
$$(T_{adj}^a)^{bc} = -i f^{abc}.\tag1 $$
Then he says that this satisfies the Lie algebra
$$[T^a,T^b]= i f^{abc}T^c. \tag2 $$
To prove this he says that (Eq. 1) is substituted into (Eq. 2.) and with the use of the Jacobi identity
$f^{abd}f^{cde}+f^{bcd}f^{ade}+f^{cad}f^{bde}=0$
it is shown that the Lie algebra is satisfied.
My Problem:
So as he says I wanted to substitute (Eq. 1) into (Eq. 2.) but get really confused by all the indices. So Im actually just stuck at the beginning. This is what I have written down
$[(T^a)^{bd},(T^c)^{ed}]= (T^a)^{bd} (T^c)^{de}+ (T^c)^{ed} (T^a)^{db} $
I understand I need to use the Jacobi identity to obtain the right hand side of (Eq. 2.) but I don't see how.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377429/2451

It's easier if you do this index free.
Define the "ad" action  of $A$ on $B$ by ${\rm ad}(A) B= [A,B]$. Then
rewrite the usual form of Jacobi
$$
[A,[B,C]]+ [B,[C,A]]+[C,[A,B]]=0
$$
as
$$ 
[A,[B,C]]- [B,[A,C]]=[[A,B],C].
$$
This is
$$
   {\rm ad}(A) ({\rm ad}(B)C) -{\rm ad}(B) ({\rm ad}(A)C)\\
\stackrel{\rm def}{=}[{\rm ad}(A), {\rm ad}(B)]C \\
 = {\rm ad}([A,B])C.
$$
In other words the commutator of the "ad"  actions is the Ad action of the commutator:
$$ 
[{\rm ad}(A), {\rm ad}(B)]= {\rm ad}([A,B])
$$
To get the matrices take $A$ etc be generators $T_a$ and  remember how operators acting on a basis set relate to matrices (i.e you must write the matrix to the right  of the basis vectors)
$$
{\rm ad}(T_a) T_b = T_c {({\rm ad}(T_a))^c}_b
$$
while
$$
{\rm ad}(T_a) T_b= [T_a,T_b]=i{f_{ab}}^c T_c
$$
so the corrseponding matrices ${\rm ad}(T_a)$ have entries
$$
{({\rm ad}(T_a))^c}_b= i {f_{ab}}^c.
$$
Note that your book is confusing as it does not distinguish upstairs and downstairs indices. In particular he seems to assume that $f_{abc}$ is antisymmetric in it's second pair of indices. This is only true after the indices lowered by means of the Killing metric tensor.

Why can we define the ad action as ad(A)B=[A,B]?

At Gogman96 X  Why not?  We can define what we like --- and  that is the standard  definition of the "ad" operation. It is defined that way so that it is a representation of the algebra.

You need to think of $T^a$ as matrices and $[T^a,T^b]$ as the matrix commutator. I'll start you off,
\begin{align}
[T^a,T^b]^{cd} &= (T^aT^b)^{cd} - (T^b T^a)^{cd} \\
&= (T^a )^{ce} (T^b)^{ed} - (T^b)^{ce} (T^a)^{ed}
\end{align}

Thanks a lot. But I'm still stuck :(. I inserted the structure constant in your last line.
So I get $-f^{ace}f^{bed}+f^{bce}f^{aed}$. Since I need a matrix $T^c$ on the rhs, I thought of inserting
$f^{bce}f^{aed}= -f^{cae}f^{bed} - f^{abe}f^{ced}$
(obtained from the Jacobi identity) for the left term, but this doesn't really help me :(.

It does help you. Try again.

Thanks for the encouragement. I will try again tomorrow and hopefully manage it then, because right now my paper sheet is filled with structure constants and my brain is steaming.
