Generators of rotations: $[J_i, J_j] = \epsilon_{ijk} J_k$ and $(J_i)_{jk} = -\epsilon_{ijk}$. Is this a coincidence?
Thinking about $SO(3)$. Any rotation matrix $R$ can be written
$$
R = e^{\theta \hat{n}\cdot J}
$$
where $J$ is a vector the three skew-symmetric generators of rotation $J_x$, $J_y$, and $J_z$. In this case $R$ representation a rotation of angle $\theta$ about axis $\hat{n}$. These three $J$ matrices can be written as
\begin{align*}
J_x =& \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
J_y =& \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
J_z =& \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
We have
$$
[J_i, J_j] = \epsilon_{ijk} J_k
$$
Thinking of the space spanned by the $J_i$ matrices as the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ of the Lie group $SO(3)$ we can understand that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ are the structure coefficients of the Lie algebra.
However, in this case we ALSO have the property that
$$
(J_i)_{kj} = -\epsilon_{ijk}
$$
So the matrix elements of the action of the $J_i$ matrices on $\mathbb{R}^3$ are also given by $\epsilon_{ijk}$. We have
$$
[J_i, J_j] = -(J_i)_{jk} J_k
$$
Is this a coincidence? Or is there some deeper Lie or representation theory reason why this is expected?

this is called the adjoint representation. it exists for any simple lie algebra

Have you learned about the Jacobi identity?

@AccidentalFourierTransform do you mean "simple" Lie algebra in the technical sense like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_algebra

@CosmasZachos I know what the Jacobi identity is, I know that Lie algebras satisfy it. That's all.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/812940/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377429/2451 and links therein.

Well, you then know that the structure constants satisfy the commutation relations for the Lie algebra, and you are done: not a coincidence.

@AccidentalFourierTransform my book has "semi-simple" in the title, it also asserts that the wonders of the adjoint rep don't appear until  $SU(3)$ (I think because in $SO(3)$ the adjoint and fundamental reps are both 3 dimensional), but it's been "a minute" since I opened it.

This is not a coincidence. The three matrices you have chosen as generators for your rotations live in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. This explicit matrix elements of the adjoint representation are always given by the structure constants themselves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation)

Ok, so in particular, if we had another representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ like $\sigma_{x,y,z}$, the Pauli matrices, we wouldn't be surprised to find $[\sigma_i, \sigma_j] \propto (J_i)_{jk}\sigma_k$. That is, commutation relations of any representation of a Lie algebra are always going to be given by matrix coefficients of elements of THE adjoint representation?

That is correct, the structure constants always give the matrix elements of the adjoint representation.

I feel like this is a dumb question but asking anyways: I didn't know that "the three matrices I have chosen as generators for [my] rotations live in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$". How can I tell that my matrices are in the adjoint representation?

That is a non trivial question (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416420/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-representation-is-or-is-not-the-adjoint-representati), I would say that for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ one would know that the $\mathbf{3}$ rep is the defining one and it just so happens to be the adjoint here.

Perhaps the fact that $(J_i){jk} \propto f{ijk}$ is the evidence that $J_i$ generate the adjoint representation. And the thing I should not be surprised by is the fact that there is some representation which satisfies this (namely the adjoint representation exists).

@Jagerber48 the adjoint representation has the same dimension as the algebra.  It is constructed by considering the action of the operator $A$ on  $B$, with $B$ considered as a vector in the vector space of matrices, and the action given by the commutator $[A,B]$.  This gives a linear combination of the other generators where the coefficients are precisely the structure constants.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287521/question-3-chapter-4-in-brian-halls-lie-groups-lie-algebras-and-their-represen which shows that adjoint representation is equivalent (isomorphic?) to the "standard" representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ (like wise for $SO(3)$).
