Definition of adjoint representation in "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" by Howard Georgi
In the book "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" by Howard Georgi, on page 48, he defines:
\begin{align}
[T_a]_{bc}\equiv-i f_{abc}
\end{align}
where $f_{abc}$ is structure constant. The author then calls it "adjoint representation". I didn't understand what he means.
Then I looked up Wikipedia's "Adjoint representation" article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation. They define adjoint representation as follows:

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over some field. Given an element $x$ of a Lie algebra
$\mathfrak{g}$, one defines the adjoint action of $x$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ as the map
\begin{align}
\text{ad}_x:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}\hspace{1cm}\text{with}\hspace{1cm}\text{ad}_x(y)=[x,y]
\end{align}
for all $y$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. It is called the adjoint endomorphism or adjoint action. Since a bracket is bilinear, this determines the linear mapping
\begin{align}
\text{ad}:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{gl(g)}
\end{align}
given by $x\mapsto\text{ad}_x$.

Then, they derive the matrix elements for $[\text{ad}_{e^{\hspace{0.05cm}a}}]$ as follows:

The explicit matrix elements of the adjoint representation are given by the structure constants of the algebra. That is, let {$e^a$} be a set of basis vectors for the algebra, with
\begin{align}
[e^a,e^b]=\sum_c c^{ab}_{\;\;\,c}\,e^c.
\end{align}
Then the matrix elements for $[\text{ad}_{e^{\hspace{0.05cm}a}}]$ are given by
\begin{align}
[\text{ad}_{e^{\hspace{0.05cm}a}}]_b^{\,\,c}=c^{ac}_{\;\;\,b}
\end{align}

where I changed the indices to {$a,b,c,...$}. As far as I understand, $c^{ab}_{\;\;\,c}$ is the same as structure constant $f_{abc}$(up to imaginary unit i).
My questions are:

Ignoring the imaginary number $i$, are Georgi's $T_a$ and Wiki's $\text{ad}_{e^{\hspace{0.05cm}a}}$ the same?
If they are the same, then the formula for $[T_a]_{bc}$ in Georgi's book seems incorrect. I think it should be $[T_a]_{bc}\equiv i f_{acb}$. Am I misunderstanding something?
If they are not then what is $T_a$ exactly? Is it an operator acting on Lie algebra? Can we define it without referring to matrix elements like the way Wiki define $\text{ad}_x$?


Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377429/2451 and links therein.

Are you aware that the structure constants are completely antisymmetric, i.e. $f_{abc} = - f_{acb}$ ?

@mb28025 Are they? I only know they are antisymmetric in the first two indices, i.e. $f_{abc}=-f_{bac}$. I can't see why $f_{abc}=-f_{acb}$

@mb28025 I just looked up on Wiki and found that "The structure constants are completely anti-symmetric in all indices if and only if the Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple compact Lie algebras". However Georgi's book doesn't mention anything like that before introducing adjoint representation.

I agree, you need additional assumptions. Indeed, Georgi shows the antisymmetricity of the structure constants using the Killing form a bit later on page 50. I'm not sure if this is satisfactory enough, but in (most) physical cases (e.g. $SU(N)$) the assumptions hold and one can consider the structure constants completely antisymmetric.

@mb28025 I see. Thanks for your answers.
